# Read file in a new terminal with 'gnome-terminal --'

Tags: scripts, python, gnome-terminal

I want to automatize some processes for my work, so i wrighting python script to do that. I want to read file data in a new terminal, so i have a function on my python script:

```
os.chdir("/home/andrej/Desctop/.kjk")
os.system(f"gnome-terminal -- 'cat site.txt'")
```

and i have 'no such file or directory' error. As i readed gnome-terminal dont do 'cat' command, so i write another python file, that should read data for me and print it in new console, but error is same.

```
os.chdir("/home/andrej/Desctop/.kjk")
os.system(f"gnome-terminal -- 'python3 read.py'")
```

All works perfectly from the same terminal where i executing commands from, but i just cant do it from new one.

Another functions running in new terminal correctly, for example:

```
os.system(f"gnome-terminal -e 'sshpass -p {self.spassw} ssh {self.username}@{self.ip}'")
```

So how can i just simply read a file from a new gnome-terminal, or what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The `gnome-terminal` command expects `-- command` to optionally be followed by **list of positional parameters**. When you do

```
os.system(f"gnome-terminal -- 'cat site.txt'")
```

or

```
os.system(f"gnome-terminal -- 'python3 read.py'")
```

it tries to execute `'cat site.txt'` or `'python3 read.py'` as a single command, rather than a command + arguments.

Instead you can do

```
import os,subprocess

os.chdir("/home/andrej/Desctop/.kjk")
subprocess.call(["gnome-terminal", "--", "cat", "site.txt"])
```

or

```
import os,subprocess

os.chdir("/home/andrej/Desctop/.kjk")
subprocess.call(["gnome-terminal", "--", "python3", "read.py"])
```

Reference:

- [Passing arguments into os.system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14892355/passing-arguments-into-os-system)

Comment: yep, i tryed to use subprocess, but i cant get correct effect. Your code just opening new terminal without file text in it, unfortuanally

Comment: It works this way in SAME terminal, but not working if i opening new one

Comment: @AndrejVilenskij did you include the `os.chdir()`? you will still need to make sure you are executing the command in the directory that contains your file

Comment: chdir is on the same place. Looks like problem is in something else

Comment: OK... works for me :shrug: