# Launching an executable with sudo on startup - command not found

Tags: permissions, scripts, sudo, startup

So there's a program I am developing and in order to use its full intended functionality, I need it to run with root privileges - otherwise it can't access /dev/spidev0.0. I have to get it to run on system startup with root privileges.

I have created a script that changes into the directory that contains my executable, and runs a terminal instance, passing the command to run the executable as an argument, as in

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/username/app/build
gnome-terminal -- "sudo ./app"
```

and placed it in Startup Applications. Upon rebooting the board, I get a terminal instance with an error message reading "no such file or directory". Everything runs smoothly, though, should I remove the "sudo" part. The problem is, I need the "sudo".

`sudo ./app` works just fine if used in terminal when the system has already started. I also tried placing a copy of my executable in /usr/bin and /sbin, and launch them via the script with a `gnome-terminal -- "sudo app"`, to no avail.

How do I properly run an executable on startup with root privileges, if it is at all possible? My version of Ubuntu is 18.04 LTS, if that is of any substance.

Comment: Is it a headless service? Or does it generate output requiring a display?

Comment: Remove the quotes - `gnome-terminal --` expects to be followed by a list of positional parameters rather than a single string. See the related [Read file in a new terminal with 'gnome-terminal --'](https://askubuntu.com/a/1205491/178692)

Comment: @user535733 In perfect conditions, it functions like a headless app, but I need to be able to control it from a terminal for debugging purposes and in case something goes wrong when I test it in a full setup in which it will be eventually deployed.

Comment: Generally you would start/stop a headless app using a systemd .service file (after you get the bugs worked out, obviously), It will happily run as root, and can be easily integrated into the boot process that way. Alternately, if that's not the direction you want to go in, look at chowning the *group* that owns /dev/spidev, and then make yourself (or a system user) part of that group. No more sudo needed.

Comment: @steeldriver got it working, thank you! Now the only thing left is to make it run without prompting for the password every time, but that I think I've already found how to do.

Comment: @user535733 systemd was the first direction I tried to go in, but there was no SPI transmission going on even though systemctl reported that the service was up and running (as in, the app successfully opened /dev/spidev0.0 - it shuts down if it can't do it for any reason). And about adding the user to a group that owns /dev/spidev0.0, that's a great idea, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked for my exact case was to remove the quotes in the command, as pointed out in the comments to the question. Put in the script as

```
gnome-terminal -- sudo ./app
```

it worked perfectly. Also got it to launch without prompting a password by adding a line

```
ALL ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /home/username/app/build/app
```

to `/etc/sudoers`, so the ultimate purpose regarding this question was achieved.